# Continuous function on a dense set

Tags: general-topology

Let's consider a function $f: X \to Z$, where $Z$ is Hausdorff and let $Y$ be a dense subset of $X$. The statement is that $f$ is continuous iff  $f|_{Y\cup\{x\}}$ is continuous for all $x$, but I got stuck trying to prove it.
Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Are you in a metric/normed space or a general topological space?

Comment: This is true if $Z$ is regular, I believe (it's in Engelking's book, it is due to Bourbaki IIRC).

Comment: What do you mean by $"Y$ be the dense subset of $X"$? Do you mean $'a'$ instead of 'the'?

Comment: @user46944 sure! I'm sorry, I've edited my question 

Comment: @Babai yeah, sorry for grammar, didn't even notice this:D

Comment: I can show it if $Z$ is $T_3$ even if it's not $T_2$,but so far that's all I can do.

Comment: @tryss no, it's a general topological space

Comment: For regular spaces the argument is essentially here: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2003&task=show_msg&msg=0071.0001

Comment: @HennoBrandsma well thank you!
It's interesting whether the statement holds true for $T_2$